# Running STIGViewer on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, stig

I'm trying to run [DISA](https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/srg-stig-tools/)'s [STIGViewer](https://dl.dod.cyber.mil/wp-content/uploads/stigs/zip/U_STIGViewer_2-16.zip) on my Mac. It is a JAR file, and I have Java installed on my system. Double-clicking on the file does not work, and neither does launching it from the command line.

```
% java -jar /Applications/STIGViewer-2.16.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class stigviewer.STIGViewer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
%
```

Has anyone in the community been able to get this to work on their system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current version of Java is 16.0.2 (`java -version`). I tried to install Java 8, which is said to include JavaFX. I tried simple procedures (installers only, no environmental variables) but was not able to get anything to work. I tried to uninstall every install attempt to keep my system as close to its original configuration as possible.

I found some information about installing JavaFX using Homebrew (already installed on my system). I installed the version that matches my Java version using the following commands:

```
brew tap bell-sw/liberica
brew install --cask liberica-jdk16-full
```

I still don't know where JavaFX is within my configuration, but I can get STIGViewer to launch now. I can't double-click on it in my Applications folder, but I can launch it from the command line:

```
java -jar /Applications/STIGViewer-2.16.jar
```

Comment: I found this wasn't enough, I also had to set `JAVA_HOME` to the Liberica JDK I installed with `brew`. The output of `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` should show which Java JDKs are installed on your system, and then you can select one with `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-21-full.jdk/Contents/Home`. After that, `java -jar /Applications/STIGViewer-2.16.jar` should work.

Comment: This is an old issue for me. I am currently using STIGViewer-2.17.jar and launching it straight from my Applications folder works fine. As an aside, 2.17 is the last 2.x version. They have a 3.x beta version out now, but does not have a Mac version yet.